.NET MAUI - ObjectDisposed_Generic ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name, Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup
I am currently developing an application using .NET MAUI (v8.0.90) and the CommunityToolKit.Mvvm and no matter what I try, I can't resolve the following issue.
The application (Android 14, API 34) runs for about 9 hours a day and every once in a while it throws the following exception:
ObjectDisposed_Generic ObjectDisposed_ObjectName_Name, Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.AssertSelf(IJavaPeerable )\n 
at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniInstanceMethods.InvokeNonvirtualObjectMethod(String , IJavaPeerable , JniArgumentValue* )\n 
at Android.Views.View.get_Parent()\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.ViewHandlerExtensions.PlatformArrangeHandler(IViewHandler viewHandler, Rect frame)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.ViewHandler`2[[Microsoft.Maui.ILayout, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Microsoft.Maui.Platform.LayoutViewGroup, Microsoft.Maui, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].PlatformArrange(Rect frame)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.ArrangeOverride(Rect bounds)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.Microsoft.Maui.IView.Arrange(Rect bounds)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Layout.LayoutChildIntoBoundingRegion(VisualElement child, Rect region)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.TemplatedView.LayoutChildren(Double x, Double y, Double width, Double height)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Layout.UpdateChildrenLayout()\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Layout.OnIsVisibleChanged(Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.<>c.<.cctor>b__426_6(BindableObject bindable, Object oldvalue, Object newvalue)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, SetterSpecificity specificity, Boolean silent)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes, SetterSpecificity specificity)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TypedBinding`2[[MDC_Room.Model.People.ChildListTabletDto, MDC_Room, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].ApplyCore(Object sourceObject, BindableObject target, BindableProperty property, Boolean fromTarget, SetterSpecificity specificity)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TypedBinding`2[[MDC_Room.Model.People.ChildListTabletDto, MDC_Room, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].Apply(Boolean fromTarget)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TypedBinding`2.PropertyChangedProxy[[MDC_Room.Model.People.ChildListTabletDto, MDC_Room, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].b__16_0()\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DispatcherExtensions.DispatchIfRequired(IDispatcher dispatcher, Action action)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Internals.TypedBinding`2.PropertyChangedProxy[[MDC_Room.Model.People.ChildListTabletDto, MDC_Room, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Boolean, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)\n 
at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindingExpression.WeakPropertyChangedProxy.OnPropertyChanged(Object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)\n 
at CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel.ObservableObject.OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs )\n 
at MDC_Room.Model.People.ChildListTabletDto.set_Status(Status value)\n 
at MDC_Room.Services.ChatHubEventHandlerService.OnChildStatusChanged(OnStatusChangeDto dto)

public async void OnChildStatusChanged(OnStatusChangeDto dto)
{
var appShellContext = AppUtility.GetAppShellViewModel();
try
{
    if (dto.Room.Id != appShellContext.RoomId)
        return;
    var child = appShellContext.Children?.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == dto.Person.Id);
    if (child != null)
    {
        if (child.Status != (Status)dto.Status)
        {
            child.Status = (Status)dto.Status;

            if (child.Status == Status.Away)
                child.IsNapping = false;
            else
                child.RId = appShellContext.RoomId;

            await appShellContext._appShellEventHandler.ChildUpdated();
        }
    }
    else
        await appShellContext.LoadChildrenAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    await appShellContext.LoadChildrenAsync();
    await _errorService.LogErrorAsync(ex, $"{nameof(ChatHubEventHandlerService)}.{nameof(OnChildStatusChanged)}");
}

}
The app has been updated to convert all Frame elements to Border elements. There are no uses of Frame whatsoever!
The offending functionality is on the main page of the app, where it updates a property of a given record, expecting its View to toggle between 2 images (Away/Present). Perhaps also important, the operation happens async via SignalR.
The homepage is now instantiated as a singleton (not sure if that's the right pattern vs Transient, it's what MS docs and other S.O. users suggest):
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppShell>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppShellViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomePage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<HomePageViewModel>();

XAML is nothing special, the main page has a control which has a CollectionView, where each record hides/shows an image based on record status:

<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ctrl:ChildrenListControl }}, Path=ItemsSource}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ChildListTabletDto">
            <Border Margin="5,5,5,0">
                <Border.StrokeShape>
                    <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="5" />
                </Border.StrokeShape>
                <Border.StrokeThickness>
                    0
                </Border.StrokeThickness>
                <SwipeView>
                    <SwipeView.RightItems>
                        <SwipeItems>
                         ... removed for clarity
                        </SwipeItems>
                    </SwipeView.RightItems>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Column="0">
                            <Image Source="account_cancel.svg"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsAway}"
                                    WidthRequest="30">
                                <Image.Behaviors>
                                    <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{StaticResource Danger}" />
                                </Image.Behaviors>
                            </Image>
                            <Image Source="account_check.svg"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsPresent}"
                                    WidthRequest="30">
                                <Image.Behaviors>
                                    <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{StaticResource Success}" />
                                </Image.Behaviors>
                            </Image>

Removed some code from the XAML above for clarity.
I think I've hit a wall and not sure what else to try, any help would be greatly appreciated.
I've read all the related articles I could find on this issue with no luck, specially:

.NET MAUI Error: "Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Platform.ContentViewGroup'"
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Handlers.Compatibility.FrameRenderer'.'

Update - More Info on OnChildStatusChanged
OnChildStatusChanged is called via a CommunityToolkit PopupPage after a child is signed in/out. Once called, it retrieves the static list of children stored in AppShellViewModel (on startup), finds the individual record loaded via the popup and update its status. Once the popup closes, the homepage is also updated b/c its CollectionView is bound to the same list of children.
On load, the application loads & stores a master list of children:
public partial class AppShellViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    ... //code omitted for brevity
    
    // changed to static b/c I thought maybe this was the root cause
    [ObservableProperty]
    static ObservableCollection<ChildListTabletDto>? _children;
...

public partial class ChildListTabletDto : ObservableObject, ITabletPerson
{
    ... //code omitted for brevity

    public bool IsPresent => Status == Status.Present;
    public bool IsAway => Status == Status.Away;

    [ObservableProperty]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsPresent))]
    [NotifyPropertyChangedFor(nameof(IsAway))]
    public Status _status;

The IsAway/IsPresent property above is bound to the IsVisible property of an image in the View
  <Image Source="account_cancel.svg"
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsAway}"
                                    WidthRequest="30">
                                <Image.Behaviors>
                                    <toolkit:IconTintColorBehavior TintColor="{StaticResource Danger}" />
                                </Image.Behaviors>
                            </Image>

Once the app loads and navigates to the homepage:

User selects a child/record (via TappedAsync) and an instance of CommunityToolkit PopupPage is loaded:

[RelayCommand]
public async Task TappedAsync(ChildListTabletDto child)
{
    try
    {
        var vm = new ChildDetailPageViewModel(_tabletService, _attendanceService, _chatHubEventHandlerService, _noteService, _popupNavigation, _errorService, _dailyReportService, _sunscreenService, _repellantService, _cacheService)
        {
            ChildId = child.Id
        };
        var page = new ChildDetailPage(vm);
        await _popupNavigation.PopAllAsync(false);
        await _popupNavigation.PushAsync(page, false);
        await vm.InitializeAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await _errorService.LogErrorAsync(ex, $"{nameof(ChildListPageViewModel)}.{nameof(TappedAsync)}");
    }
}


On the popup page, the sign in/out button is clicked, child status is updated in master list (so changes are reflected on the homepage once the pop closes without having to make another API call):

[RelayCommand]
internal async Task SignInAsync()
{
    await _popupNavigation.PopAsync();

    AppShellViewModel appShellContext = AppUtility.GetAppShellViewModel();
    IsBusy = true;

    _chatHubEventHandlerService.OnChildStatusChanged(new OnStatusChangeDto
    {
        Room = new Model.Common.SelectDataDto
        {
            Id = appShellContext.RoomId,
            Label = appShellContext.RoomName
        },
        Status = 1,
        Person = new Model.Common.SelectDataDto
        {
            Id = ChildId,
            Label = Child!.FormattedName
        }
    });
    // API call
    await _attendanceService.SignInChildAsync(ChildId, appShellContext.RoomId, null);
    IsBusy = false;
}



Which platform does this problem occur on?

Thanks for the reminder, it's Android, updated question too

Where is 'OnChildStatusChanged' implemented? What does OnStatusChangeDto represent?

According to your case description, the project can run normally at the beginning, but it crashes after running for 9 hours, right? So it can be determined that the cause of the problem is a memory leak?

I don't believe so, it's not consistent, some days it will run for days without issues. Also, what could possibly be leaking, I think it's a fundamental framework issue

there are roughly 150 different tablets using this app and only a few have this issue, old Xamarin app (same architecture) did not have any issues

to clarify, the tablets are all the same make and model ... I know the tablets that exhibit this issue also suffer from a weak internet connection but I cant image that is related?

I can't reproduce the problem. In addition can you try to debug to find which line cause this error? I see you said you change the Frame to Border. You can try to keep the Frame and contain it in a layout and test again.

The problem went away once I stopped using community toolkit popup, unfortunately b/c it provided a better UX
